# Recursive tranformer in play json

Tags: scala, jackson, play-json

I want to update all objects in jsValue by applying transformer

```
import play.api.libs.json._

val json = Json.obj(
"whatever" -> 1,
"content" -> "hello world",
"sub" -> Json.obj("content" -> "love world"
))

val transformer = (__ \\ 'content).json.update(
  __.readNullable[JsString].map{
    case Some(JsString(str)) => JsString(str.replaceAll("world", "scala"))
  }
)

json.transform(transformer)
```

I expect to see this result:

```
Json.obj(
"whatever" -> 1,
"content" -> "hello scala",
"sub" -> Json.obj("content" -> "love scala")
)
```

I get error:

```
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: expected KeyPathNode (JsPath.scala:138)
[error] play.api.libs.json.JsPath$.step$1(JsPath.scala:138)
[error] play.api.libs.json.JsPath$.play$api$libs$json$JsPath$$buildSubPath$1(JsPath.scala:147)
[error] play.api.libs.json.JsPath$$anonfun$createObj$1.apply(JsPath.scala:152)
[error] play.api.libs.json.JsPath$$anonfun$createObj$1.apply(JsPath.scala:150)
[error] play.api.libs.json.JsPath$.createObj(JsPath.scala:150)
```

But it seems like recursive path (backward slashes) doesn't work, is it possible to do this at all?

Comment: Such path is allowed in lookup, not in transformation

Comment: that's pity, i thought it's not difficult do transformation with recursive path